# How to join 3 traces is a PCB?

Tags: pcb-design, routing

Usually I route my PCBs never making a 90º turn as best practices recommends, but sometimes there are points were 3 traces must intercept, if I always do 45º turns, in this intersection will be a 90º turn, so is it ok, or there is a better way of doing so?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The 90º intersection will not be a issue for most traces. If your trace is very thin (< 15 mill) and/or the PCB boards aren't being professionally manufactured you can use mitered traces (chamfer) as [helloworld922](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/53206/9730) pointed out. Adding chamfers will eliminate the 90º intersection and help to strengthen the trace. For high frequency traces (> 1GHz) it also helps reduce signal reflections.

[image: pcb chamfer]

> The lines have constant impedance along their length regardless of
>   routing which is a highly desirable property. Note: this is less true
>   at the highest frequencies where abrupt corners in a track also cause
>   reflections. For this reason most PCB designs employ mitred (45°) or
>   chamfered (curved) corners.

- [Best practice in circuit board design](http://ocw.bib.upct.es/pluginfile.php/8158/mod_resource/content/1/Best_practice_in_circuit_board_design.pdf)

There are other methods to help prevent signal reflections, like the following image shows:

[image: Miter PCB Trace PDF]

The image above is from [Microstrip, Stripline, and CPW Design](http://www.qsl.net/va3iul/Microstrip_Stripline_CPW_Design/Microstrip_Stripline_and_CPW_Design.pdf).

For more reading material, take a look at [90 Degree Corners: The Final Turn](http://www.ultracad.com/articles/90deg.pdf).

Comment: "The same holds for bends with angles \alpha greater than 90 degrees"
What do you mean by that? 180>90 so that would hold for all wires/traces as wires/traces/are made from smaller straight pieces.

Comment: @Gunnish It means that a bend of 90 degrees or more will cause reflection for high frequency signals. An example is the 135 degree angle in [Camil Staps's answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/53207/9730) Although like text is specifically talking about a bend, not an intersection like the OP's question.

Comment: Also, that snippet is from a document that is discussing microstrip design. This is not exactly the same as what the OP was posting, but I thought it was interesting to add mostly for the increased inductance notch image.

Answer (score 5):

You can add some internal chamfers to the PCB trace.

[image: chamfered traces]

Answer (score 3):

Either straight 90 degrees or added mitres is fine. One thing to avoid is angles of less than 90 degrees, like the internal angles in a 'Z', or the "increased inductance" example in Garrett's answer.

These are sometimes called "etchant traps" and cause manufacturing problems with some board manufacturers. For a hobbyist PCB I wouldn't worry too much, but if you were building a million I would re-design to avoid them.